# Why is "flashplayerplugin" appearing in my command line output?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, flash

After opening the cmd.exe as usual, I suddenly see a weird thing: every output of any command that I enter that is related to my dev environment (ruby, git)  in the cmd window is prefixed with the text: *flashplayerplugin*.

Interestingly, regular windows commands such as *ver*, *dir* work normally.

I uninstalled any flash plugins I had and restarted Windows, I also ran CCleaner cleaning any garbage I had and fixing registry entries. Didn't help.

See screenshot here:

[image]

Any idea what's going on and how to fix it?

---

My setup: Windows 7 on laptop.

My dev environment: RailsInstaller (Ruby 1.93, Rails 3.2), Git 1.7, RubyMine

Comment: Try and enter the command `set` to list all the environment variables. Does the problem occur with Powershell?

Comment: SET works fine, no hint of any unusual params here. Powershell works fine as well

Comment: Have you tried an sfc /scannow for checking the system files?

Comment: Ran sfc /scannow  - no errors were found

Comment: Any chance you're using chocolatey?  One thing I did today (which may be totally unrelated) is do a `cinst mongodb`

Comment: I think this fixed the issue (it's a problem with Airfoil): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467295/cannot-launch-sdk-manageer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After burning almost a day on this I eventually found a solution:

Using PowerGrep (grep for Windows) I found that I had 2 installations of Flash plugin player: 32 bit version (which I of course removed), and 64 bit version, of which I had no idea. Uninstalling the 64bit version and restarting the system fixed the issue.

Comment: I've uninstalled the Flash player that installed yesterday, guessing that's the 64-bit version. Where did you find the 32-bit version and how did you remove it? Just deleted a folder? I don't see an entry in Programs for it.

Comment: I used Power Grep to search for _flashplayerplugin_ string in files - that's how I found it (don't remember the exact location, but I remember it was under _Macromedia_ folder). 

Regarding the uninstall, it had uninstall executable in the same place where the flash was located.

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me was a registry key added by AirFoil.  Following the solution here worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467295/java-sdk-manager-crashes-with-flashplayerplugin-in-the-input

Comment: Excellent note!

Answer (score 1):

I hate to leave this dead end for anyone else who comes to this question, but Mike Marsian's solution didn't work for me and I wound up using a System Restore to get me back to yesterday morning (and for once System Restore worked). I think my problem might have been that Chrome has its own copy of Flash. I actually discovered the problem wasn't unique to me via a [conversation on Twitter with SourceTree](https://twitter.com/sourcetree/status/313947373762146305) if that provides any leads for people.

For anyone who winds up here, there's a [similar Stack Overflow thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467295/cannot-launch-sdk-manageer/)